Integral of $\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$
My maths teacher recently gave us this integral to work on for fun at home:
$$\int \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
He tells us that we should be able to do this using only the very basics of integration that we have learnt so far in school. I have been working at this for quite a while trying various substitutions. Specifically, I have tried the substitution $x=\sec{\theta}$, which gave me:
$$\int \sqrt{{\sec{\theta}+|\tan{\theta}|}}\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$
I was not quite sure how I should handle the absolute value inside the square root (I have not been taught how to deal with abs values in integration), so I gave up on this method - (Should I keep going?)
I tried various other substitutions like $x = \sqrt{2}\cos{\theta}$, which I thought could work since $\,2\cos^2{\theta}-1 = \cos{2\theta}\,$ however this integral still left me with a nested square root that seemed even harder than the original integral.
I ended up asking chatGPT for help and it surprisingly gave the correct solution using the substitution $x=\cosh{(t)}$, which simplified the integral down to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\left(e^{\frac{3}{2}t}-e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
I am able to work out this integral with ease and this seems like a great solution to the problem, but the issue is that I have not been taught about the hyperbolic sine and cosine functions (I only just learnt about them through ChatGPT's response). My teacher said that the solution he is looking for is very simple and only involves methods that we already know, so chatGPT's solution is not what I am after.
For more context of my integration knowledge - I am currently doing the Extension 2 mathematics subject as a part of my HSC in New South Wales, Australia and the extent of the integration content in my course can be found here on page $39$.
I am asking for a solution to the integral using only the integration methods from my course. I do not mind if the solution is lengthy, just so long as it falls within the scope of my curriculum.

Have you tried $u=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$ (this is equivalent to $u=e^t$ in your second substitution) so $x=(u+1/u)/2$?

Here is a solution that is very straightforward and requires NO substitutions - It seems to be the 'simple' solution that your maths teacher is looking for.
We first start with a very helpful and cool result:
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{2}}$$
Make this clear to yourself by taking the square of both sides and see that they are indeed equivalent.
Your integral then just becomes the much simpler one (after pulling out the factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$):
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \left(\sqrt{{x+1}} + \sqrt{{x-1}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
This can be computed easily and is far within the scope of your curriculum. The solution turns out quite nicely to be:
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\left(\left(x+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) + C$$

Wow. This is probably what my teacher was after!

@tom It might be instructive to discuss the insight that led you to discover that "very helpful and cool result." ;-)

Expand $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{2}}\right)^2$$ to achieve $$x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

In fact under $u = \sqrt{x^{2} - 1} + x$ W get
$$I= \frac{1}{2} \, \int \frac{\left(u - 1\right) \left(u + 1\right)}{u^{\frac{3}{2}}} \, \mathrm{d}u =\frac{1}{2}\left[ \int \sqrt{u} \, \mathrm{d}u - \int \frac{1}{u^{\frac{3}{2}}} \, \mathrm{d}u\right]= \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^{2} - 1} + x\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sqrt{x^{2} - 1} + x}}\\= -\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{x^{2} - 1} - 2x\right) \sqrt{\sqrt{x^{2} - 1} + x}}{3} + C$$
